# Elasticsearch text match percentage

Tags: elasticsearch, matching

I have an Elasticsearch database with saved movie titles.

What I'm trying to achieve is select the closest possible match from this database to see if I already have a similar title. 
At the moment I am using a combination of phrase_matching and word matching to try and achieve this. What I struggle with is the following:

In Database:
It Comes At Night

Search:
It

This will match obviously as it is within the slop parameter and matches 100% of the words with the one in the database... 
But what I want is that this search fails because my search contains only 25% of the whole sentence in elasticsearch. (Almost like a reversed match).

The reason is that 'It' and 'It comes at night' are actually 2 different titles that may/may not have been indexed already when this search takes place.

The reason I'm not simply using terms queries is for cases like:
Guardians of the Galaxy 2, The 
vs 
The Guardians of the Galaxy 2
vs
The Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 2

Does anyone have any idea if this can be achieved in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

For now I've used a combination of the following:

- A match query alongside minimum_should_match to check the amount of words that need to match
- MatchPhrase to check the position of the matched words with some headroom using slop
- A custom script that checks the doc['_source']['field'].value.length property to check if it is between certain character lengths

This gives me what I would expect.

Comment: are you able to post your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried experimenting with configuring the similarity of the field? I think combining a more traditional statistical approach with some shingle boosting could offer you more robust solution. You could filter by score to limit the set of results.

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I did not know about similarity yet and it certainly looks interesting. Will try this out upcoming week and will let you know:)